# React: TypeScript generics, auto switch parameter-type from function (function as props)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to implement the following (in React/TypeScript (.tsx))

**Main.tsx** (edit: `botCommands` is an array in which multiple objects can be (with `command` and `botResponse()`)

```
function Main() {
  return (
    <TestComponent
      botVariables={{
        tasks: [],
        groups: []
      }}
      botCommands={[
        {
          command: "-help",
          botResponse(botVariables) {
            return botVariables.tasks[0]
          }
        }
      ]}
    />
  );
}
```

**TestComponent.tsx**

```
interface BotCommand {
  command: string;
  botResponse(botVariables: any): string;
}

interface TestComponentProps {
  botVariables: any;
  botCommands: BotCommand[];
}

export default function TestComponent(props: TestComponentProps) {
  return (
    // magic
  );
}
```

in `Main.tsx` I would like that in the function `botResponse()` the type (currently `any`) is automatically adjusted. So that automatically the content of `botVariables` is taken as type.

Simply put, if I write in `Main.tsx` in the `botResponse()` function "botVariables."
that `tasks` and `groups` can be suggested to me by the IDE. The data in `botVariables` can change so you can't just create an interface in the `TestComponent.tsx` file.

I tried with typescript generics but unfortunately failed. Thanks for help!

Comment: What are the constraints of `botVariables`? Is it always an object with properties `tasks` and `groups` which are arrays?  Do the contents of a `tasks` array vary, or are they always `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your requirements correctly, `botVariables` could be anything, but the `botVariables` and the `botCommands` that we provide to the `TestComponent` need to match each other.  That is, the arguments of the `botResponse` function in the `botCommands` are the same type as the `botVariables` prop.

In order to do this, we make the `BotCommand` interface generic, where the type `T` represents the type of the `botResponse` variables.

```
interface BotCommand<T> {
  command: string;
  botResponse(botVariables: T): string;
}
```

Our `TestComponentProps` are also generic, and we apply the same `T` to the `botVariables` as to the `botCommands`.

```
interface TestComponentProps<T> {
  botVariables: T;
  botCommands: BotCommand<T>[];
}
```

This means the component is generic as well.

```
export default function TestComponent<T>(props: TestComponentProps<T>) {...}
```

There is no problem creating a response from the passed variables, since both `props` share the same `T`.

```
export default function TestComponent<T>({ botVariables, botCommands }: TestComponentProps<T>) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Bot Output</h1>
            {botCommands.map(command => (
                <div>
                    <div>Bot recieved command {command.command}</div>
                    <div>Bot responded {command.botResponse(botVariables)}</div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

You don't need to explicitly declare the generic `T` when you use the `TestComponent` because it can be inferred from the `botVariables` prop.  If the `botCommands` don't match, typescript will complain.

In this example:

```
function Main() {
  return (
    <TestComponent
      botVariables={{
        tasks: ["first"],
        groups: ["something"]
      }}
      botCommands={[{
        command: "-help",
        botResponse(botVariables) {
          return botVariables.tasks[0]
        }
      }]}
    />
  );
}
```

The inferred signature for the `botResponse` function is complete and correct:

```
(method) BotCommand<{ tasks: string[]; groups: string[]; }>.botResponse(botVariables: {
    tasks: string[];
    groups: string[];
}): string
```

In order to get proper inference, I had to use `["first"]` instead of an empty array because empty arrays are typed as `never[]` but we want `string[]`.  You can use an empty array, but you would have to explicitly set the type for it.

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/OwEJ3N)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow community.

Typescript cannot automatically detect type of your parameter.

Anyway, you can choose to use [Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) or [Generic Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

You can use Union Type if variables are a limited set of types.

```
interface MyObject {
    tasks: string[]
}

interface BotCommand {
  command: string;
  botResponse: (botVariables: string | number | MyObject) => string;
}
```

Example with Generic Types

```
interface BotCommand {
  command: string;
  botResponse: <T extends unknown>(botVariables: T) => string;
}
```

In both cases you need to "recognize" the current type of your object before using it. To do that you can use a [Typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#user-defined-type-guard-functions).

```
function isMyObject(x: unknown): x is MyObject {
  return (x as MyObject).tasks !== undefined
}
```

For more infos give a look to this [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/rnm78?file=/index.ts).

Comment: What you are saying is all true if we are dealing with just the `BotCommand` interface alone but you are kind of missing the bigger picture.  Within the context of a `TestComponent` component, the arguments of the `botResponse` aren't `unknown` anymore because they are the same type as the `botVariables` prop.

Comment: The parameter `tasks:[]` for example is not always specified. The answer from **Linda Paiste** helped me. Thanks for your help!